# Is it a good idea if I put all this in a different function?

Tags: c++

So I'm working on this endterm project. Which the teacher said that we should use functions now. Which he recently introduced to us. My question is if it's a good idea to put every option into a function? Functions are for organizing and for code reuse right? Or I'm missing the point of functions. XD

What I mean is like making a function for option 1, which is add account. Instead of putting it in the main function. So far I only made a function for options 3,4 and 5. Which are search, view and delete functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool accountSearch(int searchParameter);
void viewList();
void deleteFromList(int delParameter);

int option, numberOfAccounts = 0, accountNumSearch, index, deleteAccount;

struct personAccount
{
    int currentBalance, accountNumber, pin;
    string lastname, firstname, middlename;
};

personAccount account[20];

int main()
{
    do{
        cout << "[1] Add Account" << endl
             << "[2] Edit Account" << endl
             << "[3] Search Account" << endl
             << "[4] View Account" << endl
             << "[5] Delete Account" << endl
             << "[6] Inquire" << endl
             << "[7] Change Pin Number" << endl
             << "[8] Withdraw" << endl
             << "[9] Deposit" << endl
             << "[10] View Transactions" << endl
             << "[11] Exit" << endl << endl
             << "Option [1-11]: ";

        cin >> option; cout << endl;

        if(option == 1)
        {
            if(numberOfAccounts != 20)
            {
                cout << "Account Number: ";
                cin >> account[numberOfAccounts].accountNumber;
                cout << "PIN: ";
                cin >> account[numberOfAccounts].pin;
                cout << "Lastname: ";
                cin >> account[numberOfAccounts].lastname;
                cout << "Firstname: ";
                cin >> account[numberOfAccounts].firstname;
                cout << "Middlename: ";
                cin >> account[numberOfAccounts].middlename;
                account[numberOfAccounts].currentBalance = 0;
                ++numberOfAccounts;
                cout << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The list is full!\n\n";
            }
        } 
        else if(option == 2)
        {
            if(numberOfAccounts != 0)
            {
                cout << "Account Number: ";
                cin >> accountNumSearch;
                if(accountSearch(accountNumSearch))
                {
                    cout << "PIN: ";
                    cin >> account[index].pin;
                    cout << "Lastname: ";
                    cin >> account[index].lastname;
                    cout << "First name: ";
                    cin >> account[index].firstname;
                    cout << "Middlename: ";
                    cin >> account[index].middlename;
                    cout << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Account not found!\n\n";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The list is empty!\n\n";
            }
        }
        else if(option == 3)
        {
            if(numberOfAccounts != 0)
            {
                cout << "Enter account number to search: ";
                cin >> accountNumSearch;
                if(accountSearch(accountNumSearch))
                {
                    cout << "Found at index " << index << "\n\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Not found!\n\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The list is empty!\n\n";
            }
        }
        else if(option == 4)
        {
            if(numberOfAccounts != 0)
            {
                viewList();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The list is empty!\n\n";
            }
        }
        else if(option == 5)
        {
            if(numberOfAccounts != 0)
            {
                cout << "Account Number: ";
                cin >> deleteAccount;
                deleteFromList(deleteAccount);
            }
        }

    }while(option != 11);
} 

bool accountSearch(int searchParameter)
{
    bool found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAccounts; i++)
    {
        index = i;
        if (account[i].accountNumber == searchParameter)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void viewList()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAccounts; i++)
    {
        cout << "Account Number: " << account[i].accountNumber << endl
             << "Lastname: " << account[i].lastname << endl
             << "Firstname: " << account[i].firstname << endl
             << "Middlename: " << account[i].middlename << endl
             << "Current Balance: " << account[i].currentBalance << "\n\n";
    }
}

void deleteFromList(int delParameter)
{
    if(accountSearch(deleteAccount))
    {
        for(int i = index; i < numberOfAccounts; i++)
        {
            account[i] = account[i+1];
        }

        --numberOfAccounts;
        cout << "Deleted Done\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Account not found!\n";
    }
}
```

It's not done yet, but is there anything you would like to mention or suggest?

Comment: separate functionality should be in a separate function.

Comment: Working code may go here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to approach refactoring big pieces of code into small bits, but taking each option out into it's own function isn't a terrible place to start.  Then you can see if you have any duplication accross those functions (or do it at the same time.).  Sandi Metz has a bunch of videos and books on refactoring (mostly focussed on Ruby, but IMHO applicable in any language - would recommend you look there for ideas.

Also `if(foo) { return 1; } else return {0;}` could be simplified a bunch by doing something like `return foo != 0;` or just `return foo;`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should write functions separately, it's common **good practice** as a programmer, It will be easier for you(and others) to read, follow, and understand your code.

So, if your options do different things, they should have their own functions. (More like it would be desirable, in the end it's up to you)